# MP4 file created using gstreamer doesn't be played on Window Media Player

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, windows-media-player

I created mp4 file using gstreamer.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! "video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1"  ! videoconvert ! avenc_mpeg4 ! avmux_mp4 ! filesink location=/tmp/test.mp4
```

And i can play it using Mplayer , VLC etc.
But i can't play it on Windows Media Player.

I checked MP4 box. but it seems like it doesn't have problem.
How can i try other way?

```
[Mplayer]

$ mplayer test.mp4 
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing test.mp4.
libavformat version 57.83.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc21b56d2a0]Protocol name not provided, cannot determine if input is local or a network protocol, buffers and access patterns cannot be configured optimally without knowing the protocol
[lavf] stream 0: video (mpeg4), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [MP4V]  1280x720  24bpp  29.970 fps  11338.9 kbps (1384.1 kbyte/s)
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.107.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 major_brand: isom
 minor_version: 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
 creation_time: 2020-04-09T11:11:51.000000Z
 encoder: Lavf57.71.100
Load subtitles in ./
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 1280x720 => 1280x720 Planar YV12 
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 1280x720 => 1280x720 Planar YV12 
V:   0.3   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 
Exiting... (End of file)
```

[image: MP4 box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player

> MP4 Video file (.mp4, .m4v, .mp4v, .3g2, .3gp2, .3gp, .3gpp)
>
> [..] Windows Media Player does not support the playback of the .mp4 file format. You can play back .mp4 media files in Windows Media Player when you install DirectShow-compatible MPEG-4 decoder packs [..]

Comment: I solved this issue after installing 'K-Lite Codec Pack'. Thank you!